# function to get only the integer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

What function I have to use to get as a Result 1 in the following expression, in SQL Server or SSRS please

```
select ROUND((3 - (4 * 0.32)), 1)    = 1.70
```

Answer (score 4):

FLOOR is the function that you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx

```
select FLOOR(ROUND((3 - (4 * 0.32)), 1))
```

Comment: `select FLOOR(3 - (4 * 0.32)) ` you can remove the ROUND

Comment: Not if round, rounds it up first.  3.99999 rounds to 4 who's floor is 4.  3.99999's floor would be 3.

Answer (score 1):

`ROUND((3 - (4 * 0.32)), 0)`

`=> 2`

[ROUND()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

If that is not the desired result then you probably want to use [FLOOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx)